# Show terminal in IntelliJ Mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I'm using a Mac and my IntelliJ community has the 2020.1.2 version.
I'd like to see the terminal to use git commands and so. In my Windows 10 PC, I just have to go to View > Tool Windows > Terminal, but I don't see that option in my Mac.

[image]

What should I do to see that option? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you type Cmd + Shift + A and type `terminal` and selects it

Comment: @Ersoy it worked, thanks!

Comment: you are welcome. You may assign shortcut just like other `Tool windows` options if you want - `cmd` + `3` maybe or some shortcut that you don't use.